# java jscrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a problem with displaying the components of a JScrollPane. Let me first explain the context. I've got one big splitpane:

```
        center = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, p, p1);
        center.setDividerLocation(0.9);
        center.setDividerSize(3);
        center.setResizeWeight(1);
        center.setContinuousLayout(true);
```

The `p` pane is shown the right way, no problem here. But the `p1` pane won't be displayed, i can see the empty bottom-part of the splitPane, but that's all.

```
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(canvas);
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(canvasPropPane);
```

The `canvasPropPane` is a scrollPane that i initialize like this:

```
        VolumeSizeAndPosition volum = new VolumeSizeAndPosition();
        canvasPropPane = new JScrollPane(volum);
```

`volume` was tested on an independent frame and have been shown the right way.
I tried showing on the `canvasPropPane` a simple button `canvasPropPane.add(wildButton);` and it has a strange behavior: it paints the button only after i hover the mouse over it's location; at repaint (after resizing the scrollpane) it disappears.

Comment: please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @mKorbel i don't really have more informations to provide.

Comment: sorry too hard to suggesting something, nor wise

Comment: i used `canvasPropPane.setViewportView(volum);` and it paints the component now.

Comment: misteriously disappearing problems (setViewportView should have exactly the same behaviour as instantiating the scrollPane with the view as parameter) would make me extremely nervous :-) In your shoes I would keep looking for the _real_ reason ...

Comment: *"i don't really have more informations to provide."*  As such, it is not really a question.  Voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it is a question, but i was not aware that i should explicitly ask "what should i do" after explaining the problem...

Comment: @kleopatra i am aware that it may crash at any moment, this is why i asked for help here, to understand the problem, not just solve it (as one can do just surfing the net). For the moment, as i have just few knowledge of swing i can't come with a better solution.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware that you are learning :-) Part of learning a framework is to track down the errors all the way down to their root. Part of tracking is to _reliably reproduce_ the error in the smallest possible context (@Andrew's infamous SSCCE :-). Then find a reliable, reproducible solution in that context (either youself or by asking) and apply that solution to your real stuff. Preaching again ...

Comment: *"i was not aware that i should explicitly ask "what should i do" after explaining the problem."*  Well, it is a ***Q&A*** site, not a ***P&A*** (problem & answer) site.  ;)  But that was not what I was referring to, I was talking about an SSCCE as mentioned by mKorbel & kleopatra.  Please follow the link in the first comment and read about it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved similar problems by calling invalidate() on all of the underlying nested Swing  objects. So for your particular question p.invalidate() and p1.invalidate() may help. I believe this strange behavior to be a bug in Swing.